# cmake: if(file1 IS_NEWER_THAN file2) broken?

Tags: cmake

As part of our build process we install built binaries into a certain location.

I have a custom cmake script which checks the built binary's timestamp, and if it's newer than the installed binary, copies it.

Here is an excerpt from the script:

```
if(SRC_FILE IS_NEWER_THAN DEST_FILE)
    message(STATUS "installing ${DEST_FILE}")

    execute_process(
        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${INSTALL_DIR}

        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SRC_FILE} ${DEST_FILE}

        # copy preserves timestamps, so touch to make the installed file newer
        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${DEST_FILE} 
      )
endif()
```

For some reason, I keep on getting `true` returned from `IS_NEWER_THAN`, so I've added some debugging statements to print out the timestamps of the two files:

```
file(TIMESTAMP ${DEST_FILE} DEST_TIMESTAMP)
file(TIMESTAMP ${SRC_FILE} SRC_TIMESTAMP)

message("DST_FILE: ${DEST_TIMESTAMP} ${DEST_FILE}")
message("SRC_FILE: ${SRC_TIMESTAMP} ${SRC_FILE}")

if(SRC_FILE IS_NEWER_THAN DEST_FILE)
    message("SRC is newer than DEST")
endif()
```

Here is some sample output:

> ```
> DST_FILE: 2016-11-17T15:08:28 /home/steve/src/install/app
> SRC_FILE: 2016-11-17T14:56:35 /home/steve/src/.build/app/app.bin
> SRC is newer than DEST
> ```

This clearly says that `SRC_FILE` was created at `14:56:35`, and `DEST_FILE` was created at `15:08:28`.

How come `IS_NEWER_THAN` is returning `true` for `SRC_FILE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html), `if(file1 IS_NEWER_THAN file2)` takes two filenames, not variables.

> ```
> if(file1 IS_NEWER_THAN file2)
>     True if file1 is newer than file2 or if one of the two files doesn’t exist.
> ```

As such, you need to evaluate your variables so that the actual paths are passed to `if`.

That is:

**Incorrect:**

```
if(SRC_FILE IS_NEWER_THAN DEST_FILE)
```

**Correct:**

```
if(${SRC_FILE} IS_NEWER_THAN ${DEST_FILE})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another problem I ran into is with relative file names. As the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#file-operations) indicates, `IS_NEWER_THAN` only works reliably for absolute paths. A workaround could be to create the file name variable like this:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_param_file ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/param/file)
```